# error in fortran example - allocating memory error 1

Tags: fortran

I'm new to fortran and I'm trying to write and compile an easy example that I found in [this address](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/geofag/GEO4060/v12/undervisningsmateriale/fortran.pdf) to read a simple 2 column text file:

```
Date    Water-flow
717976  7.140
717977  6.570
717978  6.040
717979  5.780
717980  5.530
```

The program is pasted below, but when trying to compile and run I don't really understand the resulting error, could you please advice me?

```
PROGRAM READHPOP
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: lun = 10
    INTEGER             :: res,i
    CHARACTER(len=80)   :: cbuffer
    INTEGER             :: flength
    INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)    :: dates
    REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)   :: water_flow
    INTEGER             :: c_position,string_length

    OPEN(UNIT=lun,FILE="st.dat",FORM="FORMATTED",IOSTAT=res)
    IF(res/=0) THEN
        PRINT*,'error in opening file, status: ',res
        STOP
    END IF
    READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(A)',IOSTAT=res) cbuffer
    IF(res /=0) THEN
        PRINT *,'ERROR IN READING file, status: ',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF
    string_length=LEN_TRIM(cbuffer)
    c_position=INDEX(cbuffer,':')
    READ(cbuffer(c_position+1:string_length),FMT='(A10)') flength
    ALLOCATE(dates(flength),STAT=res)
    IF (res/=0) THEN
        PRINT*,'ERROR IN ALLOCATING MEMORY, status:',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF
    READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(A)',IOSTAT=res) cbuffer
    DO i=1,cbuffer
        READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(I6,1X,F6.3)') dates(i),water_flow(i)
        PRINT*,'DIAS ',dates(i)
    END DO
end PROGRAM readhpop
```

EDIT: thanks to all for the inputs, just to close the issue, I paste below the working code, regards!

```
PROGRAM READHPOP
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: lun = 10
    INTEGER             :: res,i
    CHARACTER(len=80)   :: cbuffer
    INTEGER             :: flength
    INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)    :: dates
    REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)   :: water_flow
    INTEGER             :: c_position,string_length

    OPEN(UNIT=lun,FILE="st.dat",FORM="FORMATTED",IOSTAT=res)
    IF(res/=0) THEN
        PRINT*,'error in opening file, status: ',res
        STOP
    END IF

    READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(A)',IOSTAT=res) cbuffer

    IF(res /=0) THEN
        PRINT *,'ERROR IN READING file, status: ',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF

    string_length=LEN_TRIM(cbuffer)
    c_position=INDEX(cbuffer,':')

    READ(cbuffer(c_position+1:string_length),FMT='(I10)') flength
    ALLOCATE(dates(flength),water_flow(flength),STAT=res)
    IF (res/=0) THEN
    PRINT*,'ERROR IN ALLOCATING MEMORY, status:',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF
    DO i=1,flength
        READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(I6,F6.3)') dates(i),water_flow(i)
        PRINT*,'LINE OF FILE',i,'  DAYS ',dates(i),'  WATERFLOW ',water_flow(i)
    END DO
    PAUSE
END PROGRAM READHPOP
```

Comment: Where is the error you write about then?

Comment: ERROR IN ALLOCATING MEMORY, status: 1

Comment: What about the character `cbuffer` that is specified as the end of the `do` loop... Doesn't your compiler complain about that?

Comment: I cannot get to your  error, as my compilers refuse to compile it because of the error @AlexanderVogt also found.

Comment: I think the `allocate` fails because you are looking for the substring after a colon to determine the number of elements... You specify no colon, so you do not get the correct number of dates. Try printing out `flength` before allocation!

Comment: yes sorry, is not cbuffer is flength, the error remains the same

Comment: if I print flength the result is 1919251553 and the same error 'ERROR IN ALLOCATING MEMORY, status: 1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here is a working version:

```
PROGRAM READHPOP
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, PARAMETER  :: lun = 10
    INTEGER             :: res,i
    CHARACTER(len=80)   :: cbuffer
    INTEGER             :: flength
    INTEGER,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)    :: dates
    REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:)   :: water_flow
    INTEGER             :: c_position,string_length

    OPEN(UNIT=lun,FILE="st.dat",FORM="FORMATTED",IOSTAT=res)
    IF(res/=0) THEN
        PRINT*,'error in opening file, status: ',res
        STOP
    END IF

    READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(A)',IOSTAT=res) cbuffer

    IF(res /=0) THEN
        PRINT *,'ERROR IN READING file, status: ',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF

    string_length=LEN_TRIM(cbuffer)
    c_position=INDEX(cbuffer,':')

    READ(cbuffer(c_position+1:string_length),FMT='(I10)') flength
    ALLOCATE(dates(flength),water_flow(flength),STAT=res)
    IF (res/=0) THEN
    PRINT*,'ERROR IN ALLOCATING MEMORY, status:',res
        CLOSE(UNIT=lun)
        STOP
    END IF

    DO i=1,flength
        READ(UNIT=lun,FMT='(I6,F6.3)') dates(i),water_flow(i)
        PRINT*,'DIAS ',dates(i)
    END DO
end PROGRAM readhpop
```

Issues:

- `water_flow` needs to be allocated
- When determining `flength`: `flength` is an integer, so read it as an integer (here: `'(I10)'`). The number of dates is expected after a colon, so change `st.dat` to:

```
Date Water-flow: 5
717976 7.140
717977 6.570
717978 6.040
717979 5.780
717980 5.530
```

- Loop over `flength` instead of `cbuffer`
- One read statement too much - you are trying to read beyond the end of the file...

Comment: thank you very much, it was not a very good example to follow to learn, regards

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
    READ(cbuffer(c_position+1:string_length),FMT='(A10)') flength
```

you read an integer value under a character edit descriptor.  This may well return a value in `flength` which exceeds any reasonable value for your allocatable array.  For example, in a quick test I got a value of  `538981169`.  Change that line to

```
    READ(cbuffer(c_position+1:string_length),'(i)') flength
```